# Disable Geolocation in Azure Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, privacy

I am creating an open source project in which I am adding metrics using Application Insights to a desktop application. I would like to keep privacy at the forefront of the data collection, and so am taking pains to not collect any more data than absolutely necessary, and in general, no personally identifiable information at all. I seem to have generally succeeded in wiping the data that is sent to the server, here is an example data upload:

```
{"ver":1,"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.guid.Event","time":"2020-04-25T03:31:15.464+0200","sampleRate":100.0,"iKey":"guid","tags":{"ai.internal.nodeName":"aeb804e4-c649-4a9c-bd57-905c7e81abf3","ai.session.id":"aeb804e4-c649-4a9c-bd57-905c7e81abf3","ai.session.isNew":"true"},"data":{"baseType":"EventData","baseData":{"ver":2,"name":"application.startupMode","properties":{"mode":"help"}}}
```

Other than the instrumentation key which I scrubbed, this is the full data I'm sending, as you can see, nothing about the user at all. The session id resets each run of the program. However, the geolocation appears to be happening anyways, and I can see more details in Application Insights than I want, and it's detailed down to the city. I do not have enough users for this to be anonymized, so probably each city is a unique user (even probably some entire countries), and there would not be enough duplication among users for this to be irreversible.

[image: Image from the portal]

I have scrubbed the geolocation data from this image.

Therefore, I would like to prevent this data from being logged at all, or at least not accessible to me. Is this possible to do? I would even be ok with faking the data, though I would prefer not having to set up a proxy server or something complicated like that.

Comment: What's kind of the open source project? a .net core web project? or others?

Comment: It's actually a java desktop application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is possible, by explicitly setting city/state/country yourself.  if any of those are set in the incoming events, then the GeoIP lookup based on the IP address is not done.

see the [bond specification](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/develop/BASE/Schema/PublicSchema/ContextTagKeys.bond), relevant parts here:

```
[Description("The IP address of the client device. IPv4 and IPv6 are supported. Information in the location context fields is always about the end user. When telemetry is sent from a service, the location context is about the user that initiated the operation in the service.")]
[MaxStringLength("46")]
200: string      LocationIp = "ai.location.ip";

[Description("The country of the client device. If any of Country, Province, or City is specified, those values will be preferred over geolocation of the IP address field. Information in the location context fields is always about the end user. When telemetry is sent from a service, the location context is about the user that initiated the operation in the service.")]
[MaxStringLength("256")]
201: string      LocationCountry = "ai.location.country";

[Description("The province/state of the client device. If any of Country, Province, or City is specified, those values will be preferred over geolocation of the IP address field. Information in the location context fields is always about the end user. When telemetry is sent from a service, the location context is about the user that initiated the operation in the service.")]
[MaxStringLength("256")]
202: string      LocationProvince = "ai.location.province";

[Description("The city of the client device. If any of Country, Province, or City is specified, those values will be preferred over geolocation of the IP address field. Information in the location context fields is always about the end user. When telemetry is sent from a service, the location context is about the user that initiated the operation in the service.")]
[MaxStringLength("256")]
203: string      LocationCity = "ai.location.city";
```

I'm not 100% sure how to set them in the Java sdk, but I know that the backend supports it (as i was the one who added it a long long time ago)

hypothetically you could just set `context.country` to the string `"Unknown"` or something to get all the rest of those fields to not be generated.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the information. I saw this before, but just don't know how to set the country property(I'm using .net core, and the context has no property country). Could you please provide more details? Thanks very much.

Comment: according to https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/7633ae849edc826a8547745b6bf9f3174715d4bd/BASE/Test/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Test/ApplicationInsightsTypes/Generated/ContextTagKeys_types.cs#L80 it looks like it might be `LocationCountry` ?

Comment: Actually, no such property. There is only Ip property, not sure if I'm missing something.

Comment: if it isn't in `LocationContext` (the test imply ip is the only thing) i'd post in the github repo there.  all of those classs *should* be getting generated from the bond spec above, not hand coded. (https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues)

Comment: I ended up bypassing the SDK, since adding that alone nearly doubles my distributable jar file, but I did end up grabbing most of the Bond generated bean classes, and constructing the JSON myself. Since I've got full control of the data myself now, this is trivial. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @JohnGardner The bond specification link is broken and ai.location.ip is not working. I am trying to set location specific data to blank( i wanted to remove it but not able to find its solution ) so  doing => in an Telementry initializer in and angular 
 application . envelope.tags['ai.internal.sdkVersion'] = '-';
      envelope.tags['ai.location.country'] = '-';
      envelope.tags['ai.location.province'] = '-';
      envelope.tags['ai.location.city'] = '-';
      envelope.tags['ai.location.ip'] = '-'; /// NOT WORKING

Comment: @Ish updated the link to the bond.  like i said for the java sdk part, the spec supports it, the backend supports it, the specifics of how you have to do it in every sdk i'm not sure.